# Python Pandas CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

Comecei a aprender *Python* há pouco tempo e estou a fazer um projeto para normalizar dados de clientes. Porém não sei como fazer uma comparação do tipo: lê no *CSV* o campo CP7, procura por todos os *CP7* do *CSV CTT* e escreve na tabela *PNorm*, se encontrar só uma morada escreve no *CSV Norm*, se encontrar mais que 1 continua a analisar nos outros campos.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cp7 = []

cp4 = []

local = []

tv = []

nr = []

mor = []

nll = sum(1 for line in open('example.csv'))  # count the number of lines
nl = nll - 1

df1 = pd.read_csv("example.csv", names=['CP7', 'CP4', 'Local', 'TV', 'NR'])
df2 = pd.read_csv("CTT.csv", names=['CP7', 'CP4', 'Local', 'TV', 'NR'])
pn = pd.read_csv("PNorm.csv", names=['CP7', 'CP4', 'Local', 'TV', 'NR'])

for row in range(nl):
    if cp7 is True:

    # compare column with another csv file

        if cp7 == 1:  # cp7 matches with only one address
            File = open('Norm.csv', 'w')
            Norm = csv.writer(File)
            Norm = [row for col in Norm]
            File.close()
        else:  # all cp7 possibilities
            File = open('PNorm.csv', 'w')
            PNorm = csv.writer(File)
            PNorm = [row for col in PNorm]
            File.close()

    elif cp4 is True:  # all cp4 possibilities

    # compare column with another csv file

        File = open('PNorm.csv', 'w')
        PNorm = csv.writer(File)
        PNorm = [row for col in PNorm]
        File.close()
    else:
        pass

    if local is True:  # all local possibilities

    # read local

        File = open('PNorm.csv', 'w')
        PNorm = csv.writer(File)
        PNorm = [row for col in PNorm]
        File.close()
    else:
        pass

    if tv is True: # tipo de via

    # compare column with another csv file

        if tv == 1:  # TipVia matches with only one address
            File = open('Norm.csv', 'w')
            Norm = csv.writer(File)
            Norm = [row for col in Norm]
            File.close()
        else:  # all TipVia possibilities
            File = open('PNorm.csv', 'w')
            PNorm = csv.writer(File)
            PNorm = [row for col in PNorm]
            File.close()
    else:
        pass

    if nr is True:  # nome de rua e numero policia

    # compare column with another csv file

        if nr == 1:  # NomeRua_NumPol matches with only one address
            File = open('Norm.csv', 'w')
            Norm = csv.writer(File)
            Norm = [row for col in Norm]
            File.close()
        else:  # all possibilities
            File = open('PNorm.csv', 'w')
            PNorm = csv.writer(File)
            PNorm = [row for col in PNorm]
            File.close()
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Olá João, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Você já resolveu essa questão? Fiquei um pouco confuso com relação ao que você pretende neste código - você consegue explicar melhor? Você quer pesquisar por um dado num arquivo e salvar os dados encontrados em outro? Se puder, escreva um exemplo de como o programa executaria.

Comment: E se puder, inclua dados *dummy* de exemplo que o programa teria que pesquisar.

Comment: O código que estou a tentar fazer serve para comparar moradas, e estas estão separadas em diferentes colunas, cada linha é uma morada e faz comparação a outro ficheiro onde contem todas as moradas corretas.

Comment: O que difere uma morada correta de uma incorreta? CP7 é uma morada? Ou um elemento da morada? Ou nenhum dos dois? Os elementos de um ficheiro são exatamente o que se encontra no outro, ou eles terão diferença de acentuação/caixa alta/baixa, etc.?

Comment: O que eu entendi: Você vai procurar por "Rua do Rosário 10" num ficheiro que tem linhas como: "Avenida Duque de Ávila 20", "Rua Doutor José Espírito Santo 30". Se não for, por favor [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/209686/edit) sua pergunta e inclua trechos dos ficheiros com exemplo do que você pretende fazer.

Comment: Uma morada é composta por CP7 ou CP4, tipoVia, Localidade, Nome de rua e numero policia, não ira ter acentuação nenhuma. O que acontece e que posso receber moradas com erros ou incompletas.